# code not continuing to loop

Tags: loops, python-3.x, indexing

i need to write a function `has22(nums)` that takes a `list` of ints `nums` and returns `True` if the list contains a 2 next to a 2 somewhere.

my approach:

```
def has22(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(has22([1, 2, 2]))  **Should** evaluate to: True #Got: False

print(has22([1, 2, 21, 2])) evaluates to: False
print(has22([2, 1, 2])) evaluates to: False
print(has22([2, 2])) evaluates to: True
print(has22([4, 3, 2, 1])) evaluates to: False
```

what do i need to do so that the function continues looping?

Comment: Your current code **only compares the first pair**. Reconsider where `return False` should actually happen...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you immediately return `False` after the first pair! Instead, you should only return `False` after you have scanned the entire list.

```
def has22(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
            return True
    return False
```

Alternatively, you could also use `zip(nums, nums[1:])` to generate all pairs of consecutive numbers:

```
def has22(nums):
    return (2, 2) in zip(nums, nums[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this might not answer your question, but here's a neat alternative to searching for two consecutive twos:

```
def has22(nums):
    return (2, 2) in zip(nums, nums[1:])
```